Where can I find a list of all available SafariOptions with Selenium?
I am looking for capabilities, preferences, and arguments that I can set with SafariOptions, SafariService, and webdriver.Safari in Selenium.
There are many answers out there regarding ChromeOptions and Firefox, and I've been able to use some. For example, I experimented with setting the window size and was able to get this to work: driver.set_window_size(width, height)
However, many things are not common between the various browsers.
I looked through Selenium's and Apple's documentation, but there are only a few examples. I was able to figure out how to use these:
options = webdriver.SafariOptions()
options.automatic_inspection = True    # activates the web inspector

service = webdriver.SafariService(service_args=["--diagnose"])   # activates logging

driver = webdriver.Safari(service=service, options=options)

# and, for capabilities, I found these in Selenium's documentation:
    browser_name = driver.capabilities['browserName']
    browser_version = driver.capabilities['browserVersion']


With FireFox, I am able to set preferences and arguments, like so:
options.set_preference('browser.download.dir', download_path)   # points to a specific download path

# and

options.add_argument('--headless')   # runs the firefox window in the background

I have found that Safari won't run headless; however, I do need to set an alternate download path. Also, Safari is automatically opening downloaded "safe" files. I need to turn that off. I know Safari has a preference to do that via the menu; however, what does that look like in my test settings?
Where can I find a full list of the capabilities and preferences I can use with Safari in Selenium?

you might check here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250640990?sortBy=rank  You may need to write your own routine to update the preferences file.

Thanks, @browsermator. I also found this at AskDifferent: Concise, compact list of all 'defaults' currently configured and their values?. In my research, I found that the items will change (I can just rerun it in that case), and that not all items are there (some aren't present until a setting is changed). I have no idea which can be used with Selenium or how to use them (option? service? does the key have the same name in WebDriver?, eg). I may just have to experiment and hope...
